# custom jekyll frontpage, with a generated elements out of post variables. height problem

Tags: html, css, jekyll, jekyll-theme

my problem is that the hight of the content isn't recognised which causes the body to be smaller than the content which leads to a lot more problems.

HTML:

```
<section id="contentbox">   
  {% for post in site.posts %}
  <article>
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <time datetime="{{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}">{{ post.date | date_to_long_string }}</time>
    <p>
      {{ post.caption }}
    </p>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#contentbox {
      height: 100%;
}
article {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
```

I have a bunch of articles listed but the section stays height:0

Comment: Wow just deleting the float fixes everything... don't know why or how to get them to float anyway but hey, css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a clear fix element after your floating elements.
E.g.: `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`

It's a very common issue.

Comment: thank you for the answer but how does this work? I have floating elements and in between non floating. now they are still a single column